# Mongoose:create model using "1" as value for Schema.Types.ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What im tryng to do is the following, i have my models defined as:

```
const channelSchema= new Schema({
    name:{type: String},
    country_id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'country'}
})
```

and

```
const countrySchema = new Schema({
    _id{ type : Number }
    name: { type: String }, 
    gmt: { type: String }
})
```

now, when i create a new countrySchema, i use a personalized "_id", such as 1 or 2, always a number and so on, this is created with 0 errors.
My problem is when i try to create a new channel schema, using

```
country_id = "1"
```

or

```
country_id = 1
```

i get the error:

```
'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "1" at path "country_id"'
```

what i've read from mongoose documentation, ObjectId is created (at default) with 12bytes.
My question is: Is there a way to evade having to use 12bytes keys, and to use "1" as ObjectId so i can populate channels with countries?
*IMPORTANT*: im using Node.Js, mongoose and express

Comment: If you want to reference the relationship you have to set both fields to the same type, in this case you have to set `country_id: { type: Number, ref: 'country' }`

Comment: @TheeSritabtim can you put that as an aswer so i can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference a relationship, you need to set the same type to both sides of a relation. In this case `_id` of `country` is declared as `Number`, so `country_id` should be `Number` as well

```
  country_id: { type: Number, ref: 'country' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use "id" instead of "_id".